# How to add two different classes with .nextUntil to a list of <h2> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add a class "one" before all h2 elements that come after the first h3 but before the next h3 and add the class "two" before all h2 elements that come after the 2nd h3 element but is not the last h2 element.

Suppose the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
        <h3></h3> 
    <h2></h2> 
    <br></br>
    <h2></h2> 
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2> 
        <h3></h3> 
    <h2></h2> 
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>   
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

How to use something like this (with or without .nextUntil)

```
$( ".container .h3:first" )
    .nextUntil( ".h3" )
.after($('<div class="one"></div>'));

$( ".container .h3:nth-of-type(2)" )
    .nextUntil( ".h2:eq(-2)" )
.after($('<div class="two"></div>'));
```

Goal:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
        <h3></h3> 
    <div class="one"></div>
    <h2></h2> 
    <br></br>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <h2></h2>     
    <p></p>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <h2></h2> 
        <h3></h3> 
    <div class="two"></div>
    <h2></h2> 
    <div class="two"></div>
    <h2></h2> 
    <p></p>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <h2></h2> 
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is almost complete. You just need to add `h2` selector to `nextUntil` method to select `h2` elements. Also you probably want to use `h2:eq(-1)` and `before`:

```
$('.container h3:first').nextUntil('h3', 'h2').before('<div class="one"></div>');
$('.container h3:nth-of-type(2)').nextUntil('h2:eq(-1)', 'h2').before('<div class="two"></div>');
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t1d3eeat/

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Use of `$(".container h3:first").nextUntil("h3", "h2")` to get specific element range and get only h2 elements.
And for the second case use of `nextUntil("h2:last", "h2")` to do exactly the same thing without the last one you want:

```js
$(".container h3:first").nextUntil("h3", "h2").each(function(index, element) {
  $("<div class='one'></div>").insertBefore($(this));
});

$(".container h3:eq(1)").nextUntil("h2:last", "h2").each(function(index, element) {
  $("<div class='two'></div>").insertBefore($(this));
});

alert($(".container").html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h2></h2>
  <h3></h3> 
  <h2></h2> 
  <br></br>
  <h2></h2> 
  <p></p>
  <h2></h2> 
  <h3></h3> 
  <h2></h2> 
  <p></p>
  <h2></h2> 
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

Playground here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpqnaL48/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var container = $(".container")
, one = $("<div class=one>")
, two = $("<div class=two>");
container.find("h3:eq(0)")
.nextUntil("h3", "h2").before(one)
.nextUntil("h2:last", "h2:not(.one + h2)").before(two);
```

```js
var container = $(".container")
, one = $("<div class=one>")
, two = $("<div class=two>");
container
.find("h3:eq(0)").nextUntil("h3", "h2").before(one)
.nextUntil("h2:last", "h2:not(.one + h2)").before(two);
$("<pre>").text(container.html()).prependTo("body")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
    <h2></h2>
        <h3></h3> 
    <h2></h2> 
    <br><br>
    <h2></h2> 
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2> 
        <h3></h3> 
    <h2></h2> 
    <p></p>
    <h2></h2>   
    <h2></h2>
</div>
```